# Send Chat message using Microsoft Teams JavaScript Library

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there a way with "Microsoft Teams JavaScript Library" to start a chat with another user from a REACT component inside SPFx web part

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Deep linking to a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-a-chat), I think that might cover what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this for sure

Comment: Hilton? Ivrit? :-)

Comment: Chaval, rak ktzat :-)

Comment: Your deep link works fine. Thanks. I wanted to have a separate Chat to the sender but this is also good.